# rxJava remove list element by filter list

Tags: java, list, filter, functional-programming, rx-java

I have listA={a,b,c,d,e,f,g} and listB={0,4,5}

and I want remove element of listA by listB values(use by index)

so I want to get a result [b,c,d,g] which mean "[x,b,c,d,x,x,g]"

is there way to use Rxjava's filter or map ? or just use the for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might be too late for answer after 6months!!

but here is your answer:

```
Observable.from(listA)
          .filter(member -> !listB.contains(member))
```

I wish it helps :)

Comment: It is never too late to add an answer. I answered question that were older than this :)